# Postgresql: Dyanically build one query string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to build a string something like below in postgresql

```
select l1.id, l1.loc, l1.val1 from (select id, loc, val1 from foo where loc = 'loc1') l1
union all
select l2.id, l2.loc, l2.val2 from
(select id, loc, val2 from foo where loc = 'loc1') l2
union all
select l3.id, l3.loc, l3.val3 from
(select id, loc, val3 from foo where loc = 'loc1') l3
union all
select l4.id, l4.loc, l4.val4 from
(select id, loc, val4 from foo where loc = 'loc1') l4;
```

How can I achieve that?

I have tried

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test() RETURNS text AS $str$
DECLARE
 str text:='';
 x text;
 aa text[] := array['l1','l2','l3','l4'];
BEGIN
foreach x in array aa
loop
  str := str ||  x || '.id,' || x ||  '.loc, ' || x || '.val1 ' || ' ' || 'from (select id, loc, val1 from foo where loc =' || quote_indent('loc1') ||')' || ' ' || x;
  raise notice 'value %', str;
end loop;
return str;
END;
$str$ LANGUAGE plpgsq
```

But not formatting the expected sting.

Any help will really appreciable

Thanks you

Comment: What is the actual result?

Comment: The above string I have to build dynamically `select l1.id, l1.loc, l1.val1 from (select id, loc, val1 from foo where loc = 'loc1') l1
union all
select l2.id, l2.loc, l2.val2 from
(select id, loc, val2 from foo where loc = 'loc1') l2
union all
select l3.id, l3.loc, l3.val3 from
(select id, loc, val3 from foo where loc = 'loc1') l3
union all
select l4.id, l4.loc, l4.val4 from
(select id, loc, val4 from foo where loc = 'loc1') l4;` this is

Comment: This is syntactically incorrect. For one, there should be another `||` in `|| x '.loc, ' ||`.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz yes it was editing problem ..but It is not generate expected string

Comment: you have typo in `quote_ident` other wise it returns string - what exactly does not work? Put string returned vs expected to your question please

Comment: yes how can I pass 'loc1' in the string so that it can form from `(select id, loc, val1 from foo where loc = 'loc1'`  yes now it is working `quote_literal` should be used